# Trying to make a function that compares a string to a large column of other string values

Tags: excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a function that compares a string value inputted by the user to a large column of the same type to see if that value is in that large column.

I have tried to use If statements, Match statements, Vlookup, and lookup functions to try and match the inputted value to the list of the other values.[image: enter image description here[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gywD7.png)

Comment: You should also show a picture of expected result. If you simply want to notify the user that the same value has been entered previously, you can do so by converting the column to a one-column table and [use conditional formatting to highlight duplicated values](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/identifying-duplicate-values-in-an-excel-list). Each time you entered a new value to the table, if it had been entered previously, both the value you entered and the original value will be highlighted.

Comment: Didn't even think of that, thanks! I just conditionally formatted the column and made it to where the person puts the VIN# on top and it goes red when it's a duplicate.